# Jquery syntax information required

Tags: jquery, syntax

I am learning jQuery and was on first example of chapter 4 of Learning jQuery. I have 2 queries.
1) While checking the ID of button clicked we are using this.id and not $(this).id, generally we always use $ sign but not in this. Please explain.

2) While using $speech, I tried using it $(speech).css and it did not work. Please let me know the reason for this as well.

Below is my code.

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Page 87</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="04.css" type="text/css" />

    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var $speech=$("div.speech");
            $("#switcher-default").click(function(){

                $("#switcher button").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                $speech.css('fontSize','1em');
            });

            $("#switcher button").click(function(){
                $("#switcher button").removeClass("selected");
                $(this).addClass("selected");
                var num=parseFloat($speech.css('fontSize'));
                if(this.id=='switcher-large')
                {
                    num*=1.4;
                }
                else if(this.id=='switcher-small')
                {
                    num/=1.4;
                }
                $speech.css('fontSize',num+'px');
            });
        });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="container">
      <h2>Abraham Lincoln's Gettysburg Address</h2>
      <div id="switcher">
        <div class="label">Text Size</div>
        <button id="switcher-default">Default</button>
        <button id="switcher-large">Bigger</button>
        <button id="switcher-small">Smaller</button>
      </div>
      <div class="speech">
        <p>Fourscore and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent a new nation, conceived in liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.</p>
        <p>Now we are engaged in a great civil war, testing whether that nation, or any nation so conceived and so dedicated, can long endure. We are met on a great battlefield of that war. We have come to dedicate a portion of that field as a final resting-place for those who here gave their lives that the nation might live. It is altogether fitting and proper that we should do this. But, in a larger sense, we cannot dedicate, we cannot consecrate, we cannot hallow, this ground.</p>
        <a href="#" class="more">read more</a>
        <p>The brave men, living and dead, who struggled here have consecrated it, far above our poor power to add or detract. The world will little note, nor long remember, what we say here, but it can never forget what they did here. It is for us the living, rather, to be dedicated here to the unfinished work which they who fought here have thus far so nobly advanced.</p>
        <p>It is rather for us to be here dedicated to the great task remaining before us&mdash;that from these honored dead we take increased devotion to that cause for which they gave the last full measure of devotion&mdash;that we here highly resolve that these dead shall not have died in vain&mdash;that this nation, under God, shall have a new birth of freedom and that government of the people, by the people, for the people, shall not perish from the earth.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `this.id` is just normal javaScript.  And `$speech` is the name of a variable that you happened to assign the value of a jQuery selector, so using dot notation on it works like normal jQuery.  Using `$(speech)` would work if you had a variable called `speech`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`this` is a reference to the html DOM element that is the source of the event.

$(this) is a jQuery wrapper around that element that enables usage of jQuery methods.

`$(this).attr('id')` and `this.id` are same

but if the element has no ID, then `this.id` will return a blank string

`$(this).attr('id')` will return undefined

`$(this).id`,//this is wrong syntax ,,,actually it is like  `$(this).attr('id')`

`this` is used to get same `id` or `class`,which you have  use before in `event`.
like

```
$('#five').click(function()
{

$(this).height();// here this means #five(same id you clicked )


}
```

and in  var $speech=$("div.speech");

```
  $speech.css('fontSize','1em');   //this is correct syntax.

it is same as $("div.speech").css('fontSize','1em');

$(speech).css //this is wrong
```

Answer (score 0):

You use $(name) or name depending what the variable have inside.

```
var test = $('body');
test.css('background', 'red'); // GOOD - 'test' is the jQuery object variable
$(test).css('background', 'red'); // GOOD

var test = $('body')[0]; //
test.css('background', 'red'); // BAD - 'test' is the DOM object that not have css proto
$(test).css('background', 'red'); // GOOD - we can change DOM object to jQuery object
```

But in your example we have misleading variable name:

```
var $speech=$("body");
$($speech).css('background', 'red');
```